# addDomListener firing on 'load' instead of 'click'

Tags: google-maps-api-3

Google Maps API v3 offers the addDomListener for catching events in the DOM.  My implementation for the 'click' event seems to file on the DOM's 'load' event.

I would like to hear feedback on what might be causing this.

```
<script>
function initialize() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
    });

    bounds = addMarkers(buildClosed(), map, 1);

    map.fitBounds(bounds);

    var button = document.getElementById('show_or_hide');
    // google.maps.event.addDomListener( button, 'click', addMarkers(buildOpened(), map, 1) );
    google.maps.event.addDomListener( button, 'click', showAlert(event) );  // returns 'load' event

}

function showAlert(_e) {
    window.alert('Event: ' + _e.type);
}

( all other functions here )

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

</script>

<input id="show_or_hide" type="button" value="Show all crossings" />
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

addDomListener expects a function pointer.  If you provide a function with arguments, it executes that function and uses the return value as the function to execute on a click.

Change:

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener( button, 'click', showAlert(event) );
```

to:

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener( button, 'click', showAlert);
```

Comment: Excellent.  Thank you.  Now, my challenge is to call my addMarkers() function and still be able to pass arguments without being called on load.